# Getting error during while { try/catch } statement, and Color class

Tags: android, colors, while-loop, hex, try-catch

I'm trying to make an app where the user can enter a hex color into an EditText and press a button to change the background of the app. I managed to get this working, **but now I'm trying to make it so the background changes color while the user is entering into the text box**, and then they can press the button to set it.

Here is the the beginning of my main activity class where all my programming has been:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Assign variables to widgets
    final Button addToPalette = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button_addToPalette);
    final RelativeLayout layoutMain = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
    final EditText editText_HEX = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText_HEX);
    String stringHEX = editText_HEX.getText().toString();
    boolean correctInput = false;


    // Loop until a valid color background is achieved

    while (!correctInput) {
        try {

            layoutMain.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(stringHEX));
            correctInput = true;
        }catch (InputMismatchException e){

        }


    }



    /** ----- Button click changes background color of relative layout -------
     * ------- This came first (and it works) , and I decided to try the while try/catch statement above so I made
     * -------- this code all comments so it won't interfere.
    addToPalette.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // Convert editTextHEX to a string
            String stringHEX = editText_HEX.getText().toString();

            // Check for #, and if not found, add one
            if (stringHEX.contains("#")) {
                layoutMain.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(stringHEX));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), stringHEX + " added to palette.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                stringHEX = "#" + stringHEX;
                layoutMain.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(stringHEX));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), stringHEX + " added to palette.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });
    */

}
```

I've never used a try/catch statement before, but it seemed east enough. I read about it here: http://goo.gl/X2I4mA

I'm getting an error in the try statement at:

```
layoutMain.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(stringHEX));
```

However, when this line is in the button onClick() code, it works fine.

Here is my activity_main.xml if you want to see my (simple) layout, or if it helps:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText_HEX"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:text="#"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
    android:maxLength="7"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button_addToPalette"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add To Palette"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/EditText_HEX"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I am new to Android. Thanks for the help!

Edit: update with the logcat:

```
08-19 00:12:40.341  11352-11352/com.example.colorclass E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such       file or directory (2)
08-19 00:12:40.341  11352-11352/com.example.colorclass D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
08-19 00:12:40.341  11352-11352/com.example.colorclass D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
08-19 00:12:40.341  11352-11352/com.example.colorclass D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
08-19 00:12:40.451  11352-11352/com.example.colorclass W/AllCapsTransformationMethod﹕ Caller did   not enable length changes; not transforming text
08-19 00:12:40.451  11352-11352/com.example.colorclass W/AllCapsTransformationMethod﹕ Caller did not enable length changes; not transforming text
08-19 00:12:40.461  11352-11352/com.example.colorclass W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c4a438)
08-19 00:12:40.471  11352-11352/com.example.colorclass E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.colorclass/com.example.colorclass.MainActivity}:     java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: ""
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2080)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1211)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4795)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: ""
        at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:125)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:346)
        at android.graphics.Color.parseColor(Color.java:208)
        at com.example.colorclass.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2044)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1211)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4795)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can post the stack trace of the error?

Comment: soundsofpolaris, I went ahead and copied the logcat. If this isn't what the stack trace is let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you not passing a valid `String` into `Color.parseColor()`. Notice in the logcat, the error says at the end: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: ""

What is happening is that once your Activity is created, onCreate is called, which gets the input out of the editText_HEX EditText. The problem is, the first string is empty. When you fall into the while-loop, it's passed an empty string.

If you want to accomplish the effect of changing the background while the user types in, you have to make it so the String that gets passed into parseColor is always a valid hex.

**EDIT:** 
The easy way would be to check the String against a regex: http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-hex-color-code-with-regular-expression/ If it fails, don't set the color. The hard way would be to parse apart whatever the user types in, and then reconstruct the string with the missing valid values. So if the user types #ff you would need to fill the rest, like #ff0000.

Comment: Thanks, the regex utility was just what I was looking for. I tried the code, and got a bit confused. After a quick google search I came up with this: "Boolean isHex = stringHEX.matches("^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6})$");",  which gives me a true/false (a very simplified statement, haha). Thanks for sending me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to replace this peace of code :**

```
try {
    layoutMain.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(stringHEX));
    correctInput = true;
}catch (Throwable e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```